# I am getting an error "error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."dependencies":{"tsli'" while trying to restore node modules

Tags: angular, node-modules

I am getting below error while trying to install node module

```
2582 verbose node v12.16.1
2583 verbose npm  v6.13.4
2584 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."dependencies":{"tsli'
2585 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score -2):

Any error with title **error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near..** while trying to install node module , we can try below solution to solve it

In command window type

1. **npm cache clean --force**
2. **npm install -g @angular/cli** (It will install / update your angular cli)

Then try to restore node moduels again from Package.Json OR through CLI command **"ng new YourProjectName"**

For reference find this [info](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072)